# Is it possible to kill the Virtual PC Host process?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there a way to kill the Virtual PC Host Process (vpc.exe)?
In Process Explorer, it runs as a sub-process of svchost.exe (itself a sub-process of services.exe).

Answer (score 1):

If it runs as a sub-process of svhost.exe means that probabilly Virtual PC Host Process (vpc.exe) is a [Windows Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service). Check on services.msc if there isn't a service called "Virtual PC Host" or something like, then right-click on it and kill or disable it just as is done with other services.

Comment: I've already looked there, but there is nothing in the list that even closely resemble "Virtual PC" or derivative naming.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sure-fire way of stopping it, however it is not elegant.

When you run Process Explorer as an administrator/with elevation, you can right-click on the vpc.exe process and kill it out-right.

Thanks.